# Does Contextual Image Delivery support resizing WebP images and converting WebP images to other formats?

Tags: contextual-image-delivery

Looking at the Contextual Image Delivery docs under "Converting an image from one format to another", it says "To convert an image from JPEG/JPG, PNG or GIF to one of the other formats..."
This makes me think WebP may not be supported.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Contextual%20Image%20Delivery-v1#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-A5120755-11BB-44BF-991D-4DD48EA3EE76.xml&docid=GUID-EEEA6305-D109-4A17-B1A6-728211E249BB&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EEEA6305-D109-4A17-B1A6-728211E249BB

Comment: Just a quick note (away from laptop), webp images display successfully in Sites 9.1/DXA 2.2 when embedded in an RTF field, but download to local file system when testing CID in Chrome.  Other image formats are transformed successfully, so it is unclear whether the webp image format is supported for the CID module.

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I noticed the download in Chrome, too, when I try to visit a webp url in my browser e.g. https://dev1.www.netapp.com/media/hero-kitten2_tcm22-612.webp — Is there a way to change this behavior? Would also still like to know whether CID supports webp transformation. -Thanks, Marshall

Answer (score 1):

As noted in KB article and confirmed by R&D, the WebP image format is not currently supported for the CID module.
https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000013016